# Where should the "history" information generated by iOS application be stored?

Tags: ios, data-storage

I would like to clarify whether the "history data" generated by iOS application is considered as Critical Data or not.

My application stores "history data" which can not be recreated/restored if there is need.
That information is stored in the `Application_Home/Documents`.

Would this be considered as violation of the iOS Data Storage Guidelines rules?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the history data to be sync'ed with iCloud, then `Documents` is the place to store it. If you don't want it to be sync'ed, the best place is probably by creating a subdirectory inside your application sandbox `Library` directory. Those directories will not be purged (like `Caches` and `tmp`) and they will not be synchronized via iCloud sync. They will, however, be backed up using iTunes (and maybe via iCloud Backup but I don't know for sure).

Also note that starting with iOS 5.0.1, you can [specifically exclude files in the Documents folder from being stored in iCloud backup](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html). The method runs without problems on iOS < 5.0.1 as well but won't have any effect there.

Comment: but If I'm not mistaken app is being rejected if in Documents non-user data is stored for instance if application stores its settings/history into Documents, am I right ?

Comment: I guess it depends on whether that data is interesting to the user, i.e. if it makes sense that the user can download/upload it via iTunes File Sharing.

Comment: So how this is evaluated by apple during the submission ? Does the developer need to appeal in case of rejection ?

Comment: I have no idea how they evaluate *anything* as they don't say much about it, but you can always appeal a rejection if you think the reviewer misunderstood something.